# Prevent child class from overriding a method in parent

Tags: java, overriding, final

I have a main class `RecordFieldBase`. There many subclasses in the application that extend from `RecordFieldBase` class. The base `RecordFieldBase` class exposes public method `updateInspector`, it looks like this:

```
public Inspector udpateInspector {
  if () {
    return this.getBasicInspector();
  } else {
    return this.getValidationInspector();
  }
}
```

The application will call `updateInspector` on the child `RecordField` instances to get an instance of Inspector.  Each subclass can have custom basic and validation inspectors. They can implement it using `getBasicInspector` and `getValidationInspector` methods, but they must not override `updateInspector` of the base class as it contains the handling logic.

Is using `final` keyword appropriate here?

```
public final Inspector udpateInspector {
  if (some check here) {
    return this.getBasicInspector();
  } else {
    return this.getValidationInspector();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what final is for... That's its sole purpose in life when applied to a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly the reason why java has final modifier for methods.

Answer (score 1):

yes... take a look at the doc...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html

the idea of final methods is to block overriding it from child classes...